# Subtract 1 day from date in different timezone using moment.js and moment-timezone.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I want to subtract 1 day from the time now in a different timezone. The [moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) say to use referenceTime as the time to subtract one day from. The code below prints the current time in Los Angeles (first) and then the the time 1 day ago from today in the timezone I am currently in (second), I want it to print the time 1 day ago from the timezone in Los Angeles.

```
require moment = require('moment'),
        moment_tz = require('moment-timezone');

var referenceTime = moment_tz().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
console.log(referenceTime);
var referenceTimeMinusOne = moment().subtract(1,'days').calendar(referenceTime);
console.log(referenceTimeMinusOne);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter, it operates on UTC and converts afterwards.

```
moment = require('moment-timezone');

var la = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles")
var nl = moment().tz("Europe/Amsterdam")

console.log('now:')
console.log(la.format());
console.log(nl.format());

var earlier_la = la.subtract(1,'days')
var earlier_nl = nl.subtract(1,'days')

console.log('\nearlier:')
console.log(earlier_la.format());
console.log(earlier_nl.format());

// Earlier Dutch time converted back to Los Angelos equals 
// Earlier Los Angelos time
console.log(earlier_nl.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format());
```