# How to find out the timezone string?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052185/subtract-1-day-from-date-in-different-timezone-using-moment-js-and-moment-timezo)  I've found that approch on how to work with different timezones.

That gave me a good example:

```
var la = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles")
var nl = moment().tz("Europe/Amsterdam")

console.log('now:')
console.log(la.format());
console.log(nl.format());
```

Now those timezone strings are hardcoded, how could I possible know which timezone string is required for those specific users?

I need something like:

```
var timeZone = moment.getCurrentTimeZone();
var someTimeZone = moment().tz(timeZone);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it from the date string

```js
function getTimeZone() {
  return /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];
}

document.write(getTimeZone()); // Pacific Daylight Time
```